# How do I Moq It.IsAny for an array in the setup of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm brand new to Moq (using v 4) and am struggling a little with the documentation.

What I'm trying to do is to Moq a method that takes a byte array and returns an object. Something like:

```
decoderMock.Setup(d => d.Decode(????).Returns(() => tagMock.Object);
```

The ???? is where the byte[] should be, but I can't work out how to make it so that I don't care what's in the byte array, just return the mocked object I've already set up.

Moq.It.IsAny expects a generic.

Any help please?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
It.IsAny<byte[]>()
```

??

Answer (score 4):

[Setup Method With Params Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968052/setup-method-with-params-array)

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetFirstTicketInQueueIfMatches(It.IsAny<string[]>()))
```