# .NET MOQ returning a different result

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm trying to do a simple test, mocking the sum method.

I have an interface:

```
public interface ISumSomething
{
    int Sum(params int[] values);
}
```

A class that use this interface:

```
public class CallSum
{
    public CallSum(ISumSomething sumSomething)
    {
        this.SumSomething = sumSomething;
    }

    private ISumSomething SumSomething { get; set; }

    public int Execute(params int[] values)
    {
        return this.SumSomething.Sum(values);
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Sum_Method()
    {
        // Creates MOQ.
        var instance = new Mock<ISumSomething>();

        // Setup de MOQ.
        instance.Setup(moq => moq.Sum(It.IsAny(1,2)).Returns(4));

        // Instance the object.
        var sum = new CallSum(instance.Object);

        // Execute the operation.
        var result = sum.Execute(2, 2);

        // Check the result.
        Assert.AreEqual(4, result);
    }
```

The problem is, when I call the Execute method, it is returing `0`, but in my MOQ, I'm setting `4`. Why this happens?

Comment: Is that `Returns()` call in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Setup` you say `IsAny(1,2)`, those arguments don't match the arguments on `Execute` which are `2,2`

You should instead be using:

```
    instance.Setup(moq => moq.Sum(It.IsAny<int[]>()).Returns(4));
```

(See [Setup Method With Params Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968052/setup-method-with-params-array) for more info)