# .NET Core Moq Params array in setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq

I am trying to use Moq to mock a reponse from a method which uses the params keyword with an int array

```
public interface IValidationHelper
{
    Task<bool> ValidateParents(params int?[] parents);
}
```

I am findning myself having to mock it in two ways to get it to properly mock.  First, with a single param, and second, with two params.
Is there a way to specify something like params in a It.IsAny in the Setup?

```
private void MockValidateParents(bool valid = true)
{
    _validationHelper.Setup(x => x.ValidateParents(
        It.IsAny<int>()
    )).ReturnsAsync(valid);

    _validationHelper.Setup(x => x.ValidateParents(
        It.IsAny<int>(),
        It.IsAny<int>()
    )).ReturnsAsync(valid);
}
```

Comment: this might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968052/setup-method-with-params-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to tell the mock that it is any array that it can take:

```
_validationHelper.Setup(x => x.ValidateParents(
    It.IsAny<int?[]>()
)).ReturnsAsync(valid);
```

Instead of telling it all the single inputs.